# Turbolinks in forms and pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, turbolinks

I was wondering if I can use Turbolinks in a search form submit and/or will_paginate.

Anybody have some idea on how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Add the gem and the js to application.js and it should all work as expected. rails magic!
Works with will_paginate and no impact on SEO elements.

Just to clarify, form submission should simply reman n changed (at this point of time). So you don't get performance boost there, but the behaviour works as before and doesn't break.

Comment: It works in the sense that it should not impact anything and it should work as before, regular browser submit, or ajax post if this is what your code implemented.

Comment: Sure, it does work. But I was surprised this solution might end as another plugin for forms (https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/issues/64). Felt like it was more of a 'ajaxify-everything' solution at first. What's the point leaving forms behind ? Just a thought.

Comment: doknow, my guess would be that it's difficult to make a single solution there that would suite all needs.

Comment: I guess I'm might not see the limitations of making the forms automatically send their requests through ajax